# Unable to load a local module

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions

I have TypeScript in VSCode.  The code has been working for some time but now I am getting the below errors on most of my imports.

```
Unable to load a local module:     
    "file:///C:/Users/..../Dropbox/smartCity/Stacks/nftMgr/node_modules/node-fetch".
      Please check the file path.deno(no-local

> Relative import path "reflect-metadata" not prefixed with / or ./ or
> ../deno(import-prefix-missing)
```

I recently installed deno.exe which was flagged by my virus software which may be related.  I have been searching the posted solutions for a while and haven’t found a answer.  Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

If I disable Deno as below the error goes away.  But not sure that is a solution.
[image]

[Deno discussion here](https://github.com/denoland/vscode_deno/blob/main/docs/workspaceFolders.md)

Comment: I'm not sure `....` is a valid path _variable_. maybe you were looking for `..` ? It might help to include how you are requiring this package in your deno file.

Comment: should have left my name in there.  "...." just replaced my name